# I am trying to retrieve proper French characters from my webservice

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, character-encoding

I have a MS-SQL server, and I have created a webservice in C# that doesn't retrieve some French names properly. For example, I get a bizarre combination of characters for "é" and "è". I was wondering if I need to use another library, or directly mention a special encoding. Thank you! Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace WebApplication
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public void getTotalForDateIntervalEmployees(string startDate, string endDate)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vetDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            List<Employee> master = new List<Employee>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CountAndGroupByObservations", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Linking SQL parameters with webmethod parameters
                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@startDate",
                    Value = startDate
                };

                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@endDate",
                    Value = endDate
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();

                    employee.building = rdr["Building"].ToString();
                    employee.name = rdr["reportedBy"].ToString();
                    employee.total = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["total"]);

                    master.Add(employee);
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(master));
        }
}
```

Comment: In your database are the characters showing correctly?

Comment: @JanR Thank you for your quick reply. Yes, they are :/

Comment: What are the "bizarre combinations"? My psychic debugging skills are telling me you're seeing "Ã©" rather than "é", are they on the mark? If so, your database and web service are working correctly, but whatever is consuming your web service isn't aware that its output is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the late reply: I was on vacation. Yes! You are right. What would consume my webservice? I'm asking because I am working in Visual Studio, and I launch my webservice from there.

Comment: This is hard for me to troubleshoot without creating a service myself, which is a little more work than I'm willing to do. But since you can debug the service, you could set a breakpoint on the method to ensure that 1) `master` has the correct contents and 2) `js.Serialize(master)` has the correct contents, to pinpoint where in the four steps of coding strings (DB retrieval, JS serialization, HTTP output, client decoding) it's going wrong.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for your time adn help! I will look into it! :)